# Why can the simplest template-template not be compiled?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, template-templates

The following code cannot be compiled with VC++ 2013 CTP.

```
template <template <class> A, class B>
void f(A<B>)
{}
```

The output are as follows:

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : '<L_TEMPLATEDECL>'
error C2065: 'A' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'B' : undeclared identifier
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
template <template <class> class A, class B>
void f(A<B>)
{}
```

Answer (score 3):

For what it worths, clang says:

```
error: template template parameter requires 'class' after the parameter list
template <template <class> A, class B>
                           ^
                           class
```

Comment: This is helpful, because `template <template <class> typename A, class B>` also produces `syntax error : '<L_TEMPLATEDECL>'`. It *has* to be the `class` specifier.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus [*"Unlike type template parameter declaration, template template parameter declaration can only use the keyword class and not typename. (until C++17)"*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).